# Intent to contact does not show email

Tags: android

Through the following intent I am directing my app to the contact list which displaying the email synchronised from gtalk too.. I want to get the contacts only, Can anybody suggest a way for it

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
               startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code help you

```
// Declare
  static final int PICK_CONTACT=1;

  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
  startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);

  //code 
  @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

 switch (reqCode) {
 case (PICK_CONTACT) :
   if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

     Uri contactData = data.getData();
     Cursor c =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
     if (c.moveToFirst()) {


         String id =c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

         String hasPhone =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

           if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
          Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query( 
                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, 
                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id, 
                       null, null);
             phones.moveToFirst();
              cNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1"));

           }
     }
   }
   break;
 }
 }
```